# Installation error, live system does not exist

Tags: usb, live-cd

On rebooting from USB stick (used universal USB installer to write Ubuntu onto it), the installation starts but halts after a few seconds giving error:

> unable to find a live system

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the USB stick creation was not really well done. I would try to use another USB stick creator like [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) and try again.

If that also fails you can try another USB stick or a different computer, might be an issue with one or the other.